# How to download a web directory when authentication is required?

Tags: linux, wget, fetch, ubuntu-14.04, web-folders

For instance, I want to fetch the entire

> folder3

from a web site

> http://something.com/folder1/folder2/folder3

I saw similar posts where the solution is given by **wget**. But in this case the web site ask me for user name and password, which I have. I tried to download the folder with wget when I was logged in but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. BTW, I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: is the authentication, [basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) auth or some [form post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%2BHTML_form-based_authentication) authentication?

Comment: I am not sure which one it is. A pop up windows shows up and asks for user name and password when I visit the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using basic auth. You can pass this to wget with the following syntax:

```
wget http://user:password@website/....
```